# Join throws startswith error after using os.walk

Tags: python

Just a test script to loop to my entire home directory recursively. On my test server, the join command throws this strange error.

```
  File "print_idv3.py", line 20, in <module>
listDirs("/home/jelmer/")
  File "print_idv3.py", line 7, in listDirs
list_of_files=os.path.join(root,files)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 66, in join
if b.startswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

The code is as follows. Files and root are not empty at all, so it should work.

```
def listDirs(dir):
    for root, subFolders,files in os.walk(dir,topdown=False):
            list_of_files=os.path.join(root,files)
            print files
            print root
            return
    return

def main():
      #MainRunroutine
      return

if __name__=="__main__":
    listDirs("/home/jelmer/")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than joining string with an array using `os.path.join()`, you should just two strings in a for loop or a list comprehension:

```
list_of_files = [os.path.join(root, f) for f in files]
```

The difference is that you join each path separately rather than using the whole array, which isn't supported by `os.path`.